# Regex to capture prefix and remainder of word in groups

Tags: regex

Probably a basic question but seems to be escaping me at the moment. If I want to capture a prefix and remainder of a word e.g.

```
Preauthorized = (Pre)(Authorized)
```

using the Prefix as the common denominator how can I set up the regex?

```
\b(Pre)
```

returns 1.  [0-3]   `Pre`

but I'm looking to capture the end of the word as group 2.

With a little more work I've come up wioth

```
\b(Pre)(.*\W)
```

which works on

- Preauthorize this

But not

- Preauthorize

Comment: I believe a general solution to identify arbitrary prefixes will require the use of a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following also works: `\b(Pre)(.+?\b)`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add a second capturing group.
Change the regex to be `\b(Pre)([^\s]+)`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bY0mZ2/1).